# I am loooking for any shorter method.

Tags: matrices

Determine $x, y$ and $z$ so that the $3 \times 3$ matrix with the following row vectors is orthogonal: $(1 / \sqrt{3}, 1 / \sqrt{3}, 1 / \sqrt{3}),(1 / \sqrt{2},-1 / \sqrt{2}, 0),(x, y, z)$

My approach: given matrix is orthogonal, so I have to find the transpose of that matrix. Then, multiply the given matrix with the transpose. Now,  the product is an identity matrix.Accordingly I have to calculate $(x, y, z)$

Answer (score 2):

Your method works indeed, but it is much easier to take$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\times\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)=\left(\frac1{\sqrt6},\frac1{\sqrt6},-\frac2{\sqrt6}\right).$$

Comment: How can u do this? will u please elaborate?

Comment: When you take a cross product of two vectors, the resulting vector is orthogonal to both original vectors

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are two unit vectors, then the vector $u\times v$ is also an unit vector. Besides the three vectors $u$, $v$, and $u\times v$ are orthogonal. Finally, the basis $\{u,v,u\times v\}$ has the same orientation as the standard basis, and therefore the matrix whose first column are the coordinates of $u$, whose second column are the coordinates of $v$, and whose third column are the coordinates of $u\times v$ has determinant greater than $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is fine, but you can use Gramm-Schmidt also.

You want an ortonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and you already have 2 vectors. Take another vector $v$ such that 
$(1 / \sqrt{3}, 1 / \sqrt{3}, 1 / \sqrt{3}),(1 / \sqrt{2},-1 / \sqrt{2}, 0),v$
for a basis; for example, $v=(0,0,1)$. Let 
$$w:=v-\left\langle(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}),v\right\rangle \left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\left\langle (\frac 1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}, 0),v\right\rangle \left(\frac 1{\sqrt{2}},-\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}, 0\right)$$
so with our choice

$$w:=(0,0,1)- \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\right)=\left(-\frac 1 3, -\frac 1 3, \frac 2 3\right) $$

This vector is garanteed to be ortogonal with the other two. Then compute the norm $|w|$, and take 
$$(x,y,z)=\frac 1{|w|} w$$